# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: android, node.js, windows, compiler-errors, gulp

at the moment I try to develop an ionic-app with Webstorm. 
But gulp is making some troubles.

Installed Packages:

```
"gulp": "^3.5.6",
"gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
"gulp-sass": "^2.1.0"
```

But  when I type `gulp` or 'ionic serve' in the terminal and run it I get the following error message:

```
[18:36:00] Using gulpfile ~\app\gulpfile.js
[18:36:00] Starting 'sass'...
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Chef\app\www\css\ionic.app.css'
    at Error (native)
```

I am using Windows10x64.

I tried the following things but none of it works:

- Run as administrator
- Turn off Avira
- Recreate the file
- Reinstalled gulp

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the file shown in the error? Does it exist? Does it have the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes I checked the file and its permissons though the error still exists.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm getting the same error when running gulp on a Build Server to bundle/minify JS

Comment: I created all files on the desktop (new-> new folder & new -> new file) and copied it into the directory again. After that the error was gone.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that I started having this error when I tried to organize permissions on the directories and files on the project.

What I noticed that fixed my problem was giving ownership of the directories/files that Gulp needed to create/rewrite to my user, even if I had those files set as 777 I still got this error, only when I changed the ownership to my user it went away.

I think this probably has something to do with NPM and Gulp being installed on my user home directory (I needed to do something like that so I could run them without sudo). Hope this helps someone.

TL;DR;
Setting ownership of directories/files Gulp writes to, to my user, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that gulp cannot edit (or recreate) the file C:\Users\Chef\app\www\css\ionic.app.css

Check why the your user does not have access to this file or why is the file on a Read-Only state (SVN lock? other?)